# Jasperreports not detecting printer in linux?

Tags: java, linux, printing, jasper-reports

I have deployed web application on linux system. But when I am using jasperreports for printing file. It is showing this error:

> No printer availble

It is working fine in windows. I have checked that printer has attached to linux system and I have taken sample prints from it also. But jasperreports is not detecting this report.

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to send the jrxml to the printer

Comment: Also check for exceptions in the Tomcat log files and update your question (if using Tomcat).